# docker-compose version 2 как залинковать контейнеры?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Вот конфигурация **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3030:3000"
    depends_on:
      - cache
    environment:
      - REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR:"redis:6379"
      - MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:"mongodb://mongo:27017'

  cache:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Поднимаю командой **docker-compose up**

После запуска nodejs из контейнера **web** он не может законектится к **redis**. И выкидывает ошибку - **Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED**

Как я понял вся проблема в новой версии docker-compose, как правильно залинковать контейнеры?

Вот рабочий пример cо старой версией который брал [отсюда](https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/blob/master/02-express-redis-nodemon/docker-compose.yml)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:0.10.38

RUN mkdir /src

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /src
ADD app/package.json /src/package.json
RUN npm install

ADD app/nodemon.json /src/nodemon.json

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

Comment: опубликуйте `Dockerfile` для сервиса `web` на всякий случай

Comment: links считает устаревшей (но еще работающей) фичей, общая рекомендация - использовать приватную сеть (которая и так создастся по умолчанию при поднятии docker-compose)

Comment: @etki Хм.. Сеть? всмысле секцию network?

Comment: да, там же однозначный перевод

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавьте ключ `links` и тогда `ports` из сервиса `cache` можно убрать совсем. А MongoDB запущенна вне контейнера?

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3030:3000"
    depends_on:
      - cache
    environment:
      - REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=cache
      - MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:"mongodb://mongo:27017'
    links:
      - cache

  cache:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Comment: А как же опция - **depends_on** ? Я же там указал или она за другое отвечает

Comment: она описывает зависимость, но не обеспечивает связь.

Comment: Нет не запустился, аналогичная ошибка могу добавить рабочую конфигурацию для сравнения

Comment: добавьте `Dockerfile`

Comment: обновил вопрос а  Dockerfile ничем не отличается от того что по ссылке

Comment: добавьте информацию в вопрос в виде фрагмента, так как ссылка может стать недействительной и ценность этого вопрос упадет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54514/discussion-between-modelfak-and-mikhail-vaysman).

Comment: еще раз обновил ответ. попробуйте сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Вот в чем проблема - https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#/environment-variables-created-by-links

Исходя из этого правила - с новой версией хост для любого залинкованого контейнера равен алиасу, в моем случае это - **redis** - тогда выходит рабочий коннект `redis:6379`

А **environment variables** как указано в примере - [здесь](https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/blob/master/02-express-redis-nodemon/app/routes/index.js#L7-L9) для redis и других готовых контейнеров не нужно использовать.

Comment: у вас нет alias. и имя будет не redis, а cache. я проверил свой вариант - у меня работает.